# How to solve a function y=f(x,y), i.e, the functional value depends on itself

Tags: python, linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-functions

I want to solve the following equation in python. Problem is the dependent variable 'y' is also present in the right hand side of the equation as well. First question, how is such equations named in mathematics?

I can solve it if I skip the 'y' from the RHS. But no idea how to solve keeping it in place.

[image]

I used the following code:
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

```
A=2
B=1.3
C=0.25
D=1.25
def func(x,A,B,C,D):
  y=A*np.sinh(((x)/B-C)/D)  #I skipped (x-y) here
  return y

x=np.linspace(-3,3,200)
y=func(x,A,B,C,D)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What happens when y=0?

Comment: why not move y to the other direction and solve your equation =0 :

Comment: python does not solves equasion for you with just func

Comment: @user8426627 I think Alam was asking how to define a function that solves a problem like this. Alam, the typical way to solve a problem like this is to give an initial value to y and then iterate a number of times until you converge on the answer you expect.

Comment: are sure that will converge

Comment: let x = 3, y = 0, sinh t = (e^t - e^ -t) / 2 , t = (3 / 1.3- 0.25) /1.25 = 1.64 , e^1.64 = 5 -  0.19 ~ 5 > 3, futher will be bigger numbers, it does not converge or i m stupid today?

Answer (score 4):

Such nonlinear equations are often solved in an iterative way. Set `y=0`, solve equation, get new `y`, insert the new value in RHS and repeat the process. Track the value `y(j)-y(j-1)` to check the convergence. If it does not onverge, try to mix previous RHS part with a current one with a certain weight: RHS(j) = w * RHS(j) + (1-w) RHS(j-1) . Below is some usefull links about it:

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method)

Book: Iterative Solution of Nonlinear Equations in Several Variables
By J. M. Ortega, W. C. Rheinboldt

Here is your example modified:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A=2
B=1.3
C=0.25
D=1.25
def func(x,z,A,B,C,D):
  y=A*np.sinh(((x-z)/B-C)/D)  #I skipped (x-y) here
  return y

x=np.linspace(-3,3,200)
y = np.zeros(x.shape)
w = 0.4
d = 10
track_d = []

while d > 0.01:
    track_d.append(d)
    temp = y
    y = w * y + (1-w) * func(x,y,A,B,C,D)
    d = np.max(np.abs(temp-y))

y=func(x, y,A,B,C,D)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()

plt.plot(track_d)
plt.show()
```

For larger interval it looks more interesting, pay attention to the parameter w.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A=2
B=1.3
C=0.25
D=1.25
def func(x,z,A,B,C,D):
  y=A*np.sinh(((x-z)/B-C)/D)  #I skipped (x-y) here
  return y

x=np.linspace(-30,30,200)
y = np.zeros(x.shape)
w = 0.99999999
d = 10
track_d = []

while d > 0.0000001:
    track_d.append(d)
    temp = y
    y = w * y + (1-w) * func(x,y,A,B,C,D)
    d = np.max(np.abs(temp-y))

y=func(x, y,A,B,C,D)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
# look at the convergence
plt.plot(track_d)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: still i dont see how it converge, explain pls easy and i ll write the funcion

Comment: in the interval you have defined it looks like a linear function.

Comment: let x = 3, y = 0, sinh t = (e^t - e^ -t) / 2 , t = (3 / 1.3- 0.25) /1.25 = 1.64 , e^1.64 = 5 - 0.19 ~ 5 > 3, futher will be bigger numbers, it does not converge or i m stupid today?

Comment: This is not a function, it is an algebraic curve (all functions can be algebraic curves, but the vice versa is false). You are asking to plot all the points (x, y) satisfying the equation y - bla(x, y) = 0. Nothing is required to converge. The first step is to find a bunch of (x,y) by brute force using a tollerance level instead of the equality. Subsequent steps are more sophisticated methods (there are a bunch, see book by Fulton).

Comment: It will converge for w = 0.99999999

Comment: SeF, if  Alam  is asking for a mathematical method, the question is offtopic. I have proposed numerical and algorithmic solution that is closer to the topics of this forum. Can you, please, prove that it is not working by comparing with a right curve.

Comment: the feeling you skip something important in the uni :D

Comment: Show me the right curve, is it different from the output of the code?

Comment: Thanks!!! Is there any library function to do such work? Or every time I will have to write a custom code like the one you shared?

Comment: It is a pretty standard technique in nonlinear physics. Search for codes there.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation can be very much simplified to obtain *x* as a function of *y*. First, we can rewrite your equation as follows:

y = a * sinh(b * x + c * y + d)

*Note that this comes with some non-zero assumptions over A,B,C,D*

b * x + c * y + d = arcsinh(y/a)

*arcsinh* can be rewritten using [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Inverse_hyperbolic_sine) :
b * x + c * y + d = ln(y/a + sqrt((y/a)**2 + 1)))

This gives:

x = (1/b) * (ln(y/a + sqrt((y/a)**2 + 1))) - c * y - d)

You can then plot this for various values of a,b,c,d.

Comment: Thank you for debunking the specific problem. But I wanted to ask as a general question for general problems that cannot be converted into y=f(x) or the other way around. Probably I should edit the question a bit then.

Answer (score 1):

Your function in general is called [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) in the form

[image]

It can be solved numerically choosing starting value of y, then putting that into the equation, calculating next y value. And repeating the calculation putting next y value as previous y value into the equation. Calculations are repeated in a loop until y value converges. Y value may not converge. Even in this case you can analyze system further. You can try to plot graph y<sub>n</sub> = f(y<sub>n-1</sub>) and see what you've got. In case system is **stable** curve must be highly *periodic* and *closed*, otherwise non-converging system is chaotic and such equations you can throw out of the window.

Some examples of stable systems are [Lissajous curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve) :

[image]

Some examples of chaotic systems are [Rossler attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6ssler_attractor) :

[image]

### y=A*sinh(-y-C) analysis

To see if your system is stable or not - let's try to modulate `sin(x)` function with your hyperbolic sin recurrence relation :
`y=k*SIN(x)+0.88*SINH(-y-0.02)` and let's try to draw this recurrence parametric chart of y<sub>prev</sub> vs y<sub>next</sub>.

> k=0

[image]

Not much to see here, because in this case we get your original equation which has very low resolution between data points. They all lies along some line, with some small scattering which we can't differentiate with eyes - that's why we need sin(x) here !

> k=0.0005

[image]

Much more interesting. Now it can be seen, that your "line" is not line at all and has some chaotic behavior. But let's look at something more appealing.

> k=0.005

[image]

At some places sinh() recurrence wins, but at some - sin(). Let's try to force winning of sin() function, to be able to see if it will be modulated periodically and with a closed loop or not. So final image.

> k=0.05

[image]

So, it's neither highly periodic, neither closed. We've got some type of attractor. Which means, that in a general case your equation behaves very chaotically and as such it's not worth a penny. Of course in your exact given parameters range it *may* behave as a linear function. But infinitesimal small segment of a circle also reassembles a line, what does it mean ? Nothing. You can't rely on a very specific input range. If your business unit will change requirements *even a bit* - behavior of your equation will change drastically.
So the only rational step is to through it out of the window and re-build different - this time stable - model for a data. Or just state that it can't be done.